# How to iterate efficiently using itertools.zip_longest to grab data between 2 markers

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have several long lists that I would like to parse and grab the data of interest. Specifically I am looking for data between 2 patterns in one list and grab the data across all the lists using the same index. I have the following dictionary with a lot of data in each list (showing only a few in this example):

```
 LA = {
         'A':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], 
         'B':[ 0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,   10,  11], 
         'C':[ 21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32], 
         'D':[ 31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42], 
         'E':[..........................................................], 
         'F':[..........................................................]
      }

 for j in itertools.zip_longest(LA['A'], LA['B'], LA['C'], LA['D']):
     if (j[0] =='d'):
         grab_data = 1
     else:
        if not (j[0] == 'j'):
            grab_data = 1
        else:
          if (grab_data ==1):
             print ("My required Data", j)
```

This will print the following:

```
My required Data ('e', 4, 25, 35)
My required Data ('f', 5, 26, 36)
My required Data ('g', 6, 27, 37)
My required Data ('h', 7, 28, 38)
My required Data ('i', 8, 29, 39)
```

This is right but is there a more efficient and concise way to do this?.

The lists are long and there is lot of data.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dropwhile` and `takewhile`:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest, takewhile, dropwhile
>>> 
>>> ABCD = zip_longest(*map(LA.__getitem__, 'ABCD'))
>>> ABCD = dropwhile(lambda j: j[0] != 'd', ABCD)
>>> _ = next(ABCD)
>>> for j in takewhile(lambda j: j[0] != 'j', ABCD):
...     print("My required data", j)
... 
My required data ('e', 4, 25, 35)
My required data ('f', 5, 26, 36)
My required data ('g', 6, 27, 37)
My required data ('h', 7, 28, 38)
My required data ('i', 8, 29, 39)
```

It's not really faster, though.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was look for. Will give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using pure builtins:

**Given**

```
 data = {
     "A":["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"], 
     "B":[ 0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,   10,  11], 
     "C":[ 21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32], 
     "D":[ 31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42],
 }

pred = lambda x: (x[0] >= "e") and (x[0] < "j")
```

**Code**

```
transposed = list(zip(*data.values()))
revised = list(filter(pred, transposed))
```

Now print:

```
for row in revised:
    print ("My required Data", row)
```

*Output*

```
My required Data ('e', 4, 25, 35)
My required Data ('f', 5, 26, 36)
My required Data ('g', 6, 27, 37)
My required Data ('h', 7, 28, 38)
My required Data ('i', 8, 29, 39)
```

---

**Details**

Easily transpose the data with a comprehension.  Here are the results of `transposed`:

```
[('a', 0, 21, 31),
 ('b', 1, 22, 32),
 ('c', 2, 23, 33),
 ('d', 3, 24, 34),
 ('e', 4, 25, 35),
 ('f', 5, 26, 36),
 ('g', 6, 27, 37),
 ('h', 7, 28, 38),
 ('i', 8, 29, 39),
 ('j', 9, 30, 40),
 ('k', 10, 31, 41),
 ('l', 11, 32, 42)]
```

You are half-way there.  Just filter the results by a conditional function (or `pred`icate) and print.

*Re: predicates*

Since strings can be compared in Python, you can simply define a predicate that says "accept all rows where the first item is a letter from `e` to less than `j`".  For brevity, we use `lambda` to make the conditional function.   We can easily rewrite it as a regular function:

```
def pred(x):
    return (x[0] >= "e") and (x[0] < "j")
```

*Re: efficiency*

- Brevity-wise: the code is 2-3 lines compared to the OP's 9 lines.
- Coding-wise: there is no hard-coded lookups aside from the predicate you provide.  Opt for a regular function if you plan to reuse this approach.  Also, there are no nested conditionals and is easy to read.
- Speed-wise: if you plan to query your data many times, using an intermediate dict should improve performance, cutting lookups down from O(n) to O(1) time complexity.

Alternative example:

```
# Using dictionaries
pred = lambda x: x >= "e" and x < "j"
transposed_dict = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in zip(*data.values())}
revised_dict = {k: v for k, v in transposed_dict.items() if pred(k)}
```

*Assumptions*

No additional modules are required assuming:

- unordered data: this example gives ordered results in Python 3.6+.  If order is required in lower versions, ensure the data is built with `collections.OrderedDict`.
- equally sized values: `zip` works fine if you know that the list values of the dict have equal length, as seen in the OP.  Otherwise, use `itertools.zip_longest`.

Comment: No need for `(v for v in data.values())`, you could just use `data.values()`.